# How to getScreenCenter of custom view in android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-maps

I am trying to add this code to my project [Google Maps with Custom View Overlays](http://toastdroid.com/2014/05/27/google-maps-with-custom-view-overlays/) but cannot get with the getScreenCenter() functions.

**Activity which include custom view:**

```
 public class TempActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.tempView);

//suppose that I have a map fragment initialise

getSearchRadius(); //this is the function where I am stuck;
        }

/**
 * @return distance in meters from center of circle to a point on the circle
 */
public double getSearchRadius() {
    //Google Map LatLng objects must be converted to android Location objects
    //in order to use distanceTo()

    Point circlePoint = getScreenCenter();
    circlePoint.x = circlePoint.x - getCircleRadius();

    Point centerPoint = getScreenCenter();//how to get screenCenter

    LatLng centerLatLng = map.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(centerPoint);
    Location center = new Location("");
    center.setLatitude(centerLatLng.latitude);
    center.setLongitude(centerLatLng.longitude);


    LatLng circleLatLng = map.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(circlePoint);
    Location circlePointLocation = new Location("");
    circlePointLocation.setLatitude(circleLatLng.latitude);
    circlePointLocation.setLongitude(circleLatLng.longitude);

    return center.distanceTo(circlePointLocation);

}

    }
```

**custom view:**

```
public class DottedCircleView extends LinearLayout (due to exception I changed View to LinearLayout) {
    int color = 0, radius = 0, width = 0, height = 0;
    Paint p;
    BitmapDrawable pin;
    int pinXOffset =0 ,pinYOffset =0;
    Context con;

    public DottedCircleView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        con = context;

    }

    public DottedCircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.DottedCircleView, 0, 0);
        int color = a.getColor(R.styleable.DottedCircleView_circleColor, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_btn_bg_color));
        int radius = a.getInteger(R.styleable.DottedCircleView_radius, 0);
        a.recycle();

        setup();
    }

    public DottedCircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }




    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        width = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        if (radius == 0) {
            radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - (int) p.getStrokeWidth();
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius, p);
        //draw the map marker in middle of the circle
        canvas.drawBitmap(pin.getBitmap(), (width / 2) - pinXOffset, (height / 2) - pinYOffset, null);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setup() {
        p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(getResources().getColor(color));
        p.setStrokeWidth(10);
        DashPathEffect dashPath = new DashPathEffect(new float[]{10.0f, 5.0f}, (float) 1.0);
        p.setPathEffect(dashPath);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        pin = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boy_marker);
        pinXOffset = pin.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2;
        pinYOffset = pin.getIntrinsicHeight();
    }
}
```

**Customview Xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:toast="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

```
    <com.support.android.designlibdemo.utils.DottedCircleView 
        android:id="@+id/dottedCircleView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        toast:circleColor="@color/orange50"
        toast:radius="10"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int widthCenter = size.x/2;
int heightCenter = size.y/2;
```

Comment: please see this Point circlePoint = getScreenCenter(); Point centerPoint = getScreenCenter(); circlePoint and centerPoint.Is it any point on circle and center point of circle?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see understand your comment, can you rephrase?

Comment: Please read this paragraph in mentioned article above: 
fromScreenLocation(Point point) will return the lat/lng of a screen point, which is exactly what we need. So we just get the lat/lng of the center of the circle and a point on the circle to get the real world radius.